# Disable Laravel email during db seed

Tags: php, email, laravel

I use Mandrill mail driver for tests. I have a remote staging, that I seed after deploy. And during seeding I try to disable email sends, that are linked to certain events.

Placing this in seeder:

`Config::set('mail.driver', 'log');
Config::set('mail.pretend', true);`

Has no effect. I don't understand why. I place this in root `DatabaseSeeder@run` or/and in child seeders — the same. Calls to Mandrill are still performed.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You said you are deploying and seeding after deploy, but how are the tests related to that? Are you testing and the tests are firing the seed routine beforte start? Or you are seeding and testing using different commands?

Comment: `Config::get('mail.pretend');` returns true?

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro tests are tests, they are run before in different environment and there mailing set to pretend on environment level. The topic is about staging version of project with fake content for "look at it"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason your

```
Config::set('mail.driver', 'log');
Config::set('mail.pretend', true);
```

aren't working is because the mail object doesn't check these values before sending mail.  **Whaaaaaaaa?**.  If you take a look at the `sendSwiftMessage` method in the mailer class

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php
protected function sendSwiftMessage($message)
{
    if ($this->events)
    {
        $this->events->fire('mailer.sending', array($message));
    }

    if ( ! $this->pretending)
    {
        $this->swift->send($message, $this->failedRecipients);
    }
    elseif (isset($this->logger))
    {
        $this->logMessage($message);
    }
}
```

You can see the class checks `$this->pretending`, and **not** the configuration, before deciding if it should send the mail or not.  So what sets `pretending`?  That's in the `MailServiceProvider` class's `register` method.

```
public function register()
{
    //...
    $pretend = $app['config']->get('mail.pretend', false);
    $mailer->pretend($pretend);
    //...
}
```

When Laravel boots up and registers each service provider, it eventually registers the mail service provider and **that's** when it reads the configuration, and then tells the mailer if it should "pretend" or not.  By the time you're calling this in your seeder, the mailer's already loaded it's configuration value.

Fortunately, there's a pretty easy solution.  The mailer object is a singleton/shared service, and has public methods available to control if it should pretend or not.  Just call the `pretend` method yourself instead of setting configuration values

```
Mail::pretend(true); //using the `Mail` facade to access the mailer object.
```

you should be able to turn the mailer off programatically.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.
It is not quite obvious behavior of mailer I think, so your answer is very useful.

Comment: This no longer works (as of Laravel 5.7). Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53303732/1572330

Answer (score 8):

This is an answer for Laravel 5.7, because pretend doesn't exists:

If you want to disable mail while seeding the database, you could simply 'abuse'

```
Mail::fake()
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on 5.7, still sends the emails to mailtrap

UPDATE: since I use a job to handle the emails instead of `Mail::fake()` I've to use `Bus::fake()`

Comment: Hi, Claudio. If you’re using the queue to handle your emails, you could assert if a job was pushed (using `Queue::fake()` and `Queue::assertPushed(YourJob::class)`) to the queue and create a separate test for your job.

Answer (score 2):

I think in two possibilities, you can try:

1. You can set the command to enable the mail pretend on-the-fly:

   `Mail::pretend();`
2. The db seed are running with more than one request:

As is write [here](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#introduction):

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the
>   current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests.

So you can try set this config over requests, like a session, than finish in the end of the seeding.